# Multiple classes in one jquery initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using  this plugin

http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Responsive-Equal-Height-Plugin-with-jQuery-ResponsibleHeight.html

But I don't know how to make the "child" multiple classes.

Here's the code to initialize the plugin. Does anyone here already used the plugin? I copy and paste the code and put different class under "child" but its a bit redundant. Is there any way that I can lessen the code without using the same code over and over again?

Thanks!

```
//Initialise the plugin
    $('.item-container div').responsibleHeight({
      delay:    0,
      child:    '.filter',
      widths:   [
        [1300, 10],
        [1000, 8],
        [700, 4],
        [40, 2],
        [0, 1]
      ]
    });

    //Destroy the plugin, remove heights and stop working on resize
    $('.destroy').click(function(){
      $('.item-container div').responsibleHeight('destroy')
    });

    //Reinitialise the plugin
    $('.reinit').click(function(){
      $('.item-container div').responsibleHeight('reinit')
    });
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Based on the documentation, it seems that the `child` option is designed to apply to only one element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to select items with multiple classes or multiple items with various classes ?

If the code looks like this:

```
child:    '.filter',
```

---

*// This may not work - this plugin allows you to select only one child*

If you want to select childs with for one of few classes, the code will look like this: (simply separate classes using comma)

```
child:    '.filter, .class2, .class3',
```

---

or if you want to select items which have more than one class: (list classes one after another)

```
child:    '.filter.class2.class3',
```

---

Hope it will help you :)